# Displaying HTML elements in same row

Tags: html, angular

I am looking to achieve options as 
[image]

But with current code, am getting it as below:

[image]

How to get options Yes and No next to each other

Below is my code:
For HTML

```
<div class="mycustom-radios">            
            <div class="mycustom-radios__item" *ngFor="let employeeType of employeeTypes">
                <input class="mycustom-radios__input" id="e_employeetype" name="what-type-of-employee" type="radio" [value]="employeeType" [(ngModel)]="selectedemployeeType"/>
                <label class="mycustom-label mycustom-radios__label" for="e_employeeType">
                <p>{{employeeType}}</p>
                </label>
            </div>      
        </div>
```

For component.ts

```
selectedemployeeType: string;
employeeTypes: string[] = ['Yes', 'No'];
```

Comment: DIV is a [Block Level Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements) so each *employeeType* (Block-level element) occupies the entire horizontal space of its parent element.  If you don't want that you can either change DIV to inline element or change the styles/classes to change that specific div to an inline element.  (inline or other type of display type; flex grid etc).

Answer (score 1):

@Patty! Try using the display:flex CSS property, like this:

```html
<div style="display:flex">
<div>div block 1</div>
<div>div block 2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply the CSS styles like so.

```css
// use this styling
div{
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
}    
input{
  margin-right:5px;
}
input:last-child{
  margin-right:0px;
}
```

```html
<div>
     <!-- nest your angular controls here -->
     <input type="checkbox" />
     <input type="checkbox" />
     <input type="checkbox" />
     <input type="checkbox" />
     <input type="checkbox" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `p` to `span` and apply `display:inline` as in below example. In the example I have added 2 divs to mimic `*ngFor="let employeeType of employeeTypes"`

```css
.mycustom-radios__item {
  display: inline-flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="mycustom-radios">
  <div class="mycustom-radios__item" *ngFor="let employeeType of employeeTypes">
    <input class="mycustom-radios__input" id="e_employeetype" name="what-type-of-employee" type="radio" [value]="employeeType" [(ngModel)]="selectedemployeeType" />
    <label class="mycustom-label mycustom-radios__label" for="e_employeeType">
                <span>No</span>
                </label>
  </div>
  <div class="mycustom-radios__item" *ngFor="let employeeType of employeeTypes">
    <input class="mycustom-radios__input" id="e_employeetype" name="what-type-of-employee" type="radio" [value]="employeeType" [(ngModel)]="selectedemployeeType" />
    <label class="mycustom-label mycustom-radios__label" for="e_employeeType">
                <span>Yes</span>
                </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Kiran, I was able to achieve this with below:  .mycustom-radios{
    display: flex;
  }

.mycustom-radios__label{
    width: 50px;
}

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick:

```
.mycustom-radios {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
```

Or:

You can change display of your elements to inline-block like this:

```
.mycustom-radios__item {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

If you use the flex display, make sure to add flex-wrap for smaller screens (like phones for instance):

```
.mycustom-radios {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```